# Probability Question Poisson Distribution with Game Theory

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

The Question:

Suppose that you receive emails at an average rate of 6 per hour. At 10:00am, your inbox is empty. At 10:10am, you receive a message on your computer that you have received at least one email. However, you know that this message is correct only 80% of the time (sometimes it tells you that you have received an email when, in fact, your inbox is still empty).
What is the probability that you have received at least one email by 10:10am, given that you have received the message?

My thoughts:

Since there could be a continuous amount of variables in this window of opportunity, I believe it is a Poisson distribution. With the average being 6 per hour, the lambda for the formula should be 1 (EDIT: Correction from 6). This would give me the probability of 63.21205588%.

So I believe that we can find the probability of it being in the first 10 minutes by doing 1-Probability(No emails in 10 minutes) to give us an answer, 63.21205588%. Once we find that we can just do 63.21205588% * 0.8 since there is a 80% chance of it being correct. However I'm not sure if we need to calculate 0.2 multiplied by the event of it saying that we did not receive an email, as that would entail that there should have been an email.

Comment: Not sure that this is clear.  If the message is $80\%$ accurate in all situations, then the answer is $.8$ ; what else could that $80\%$ mean?  But I doubt that this is what you intend.  Usually in these situations we are told the probability of getting the message if you have an email and the probability of getting it when you do not.

Comment: Also, your Poisson calculation seems off.  $\lambda = 6$ for a full hour but you just have a sixth of an hour so we should use $\lambda = 1$.

Comment: Oh yes. True it is 1. Thanks

Comment: So you are just saying it is the probability of getting at least one message by the 10 minute mark. Then you multiply it by 80% since it is a conditional probability

Comment: I didn't say anything even remotely like that.

Comment: I don't think you can just say the probability is 80%. Because there isn't an 80% chance that you WILL receive at least 1 message within the first 10 minute frame, if you understand what I mean.

Comment: Yeah, and there was a strong chance that you wouldn't get the message, but you did.    Like I say, I think you (or the original source) left off information.

Comment: first you should re do all the calculations because since you considered $\lambda=6$ instead of $\lambda=1$ all the probabilities are actually wrong . Besides that the computer sends you a message each time that a message arrives? I mean, for each single (potential) email arrived in a period the probability of receiving a message is 0.8 or, at the end of the time period, the computer sends a message if there's at least one email with probability 0.8?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You say the message is correct 80% of the time, and you're wondering what the probability of the message being correct is? Why is it not just .8?

Comment: You're interpreting the question wrong and the probabilities have been fixed already. The question is "What is the probability that you have received at least one email by 10:10am, given that you have received the message?" It's not about it BEING correct. It's about if there's ACTUALLY AN EMAIL. Quite the distinction